# ReportViewer deployed on Azure cloud service not loading

Tags: .net, azure, reporting-services, reporting

I've a ReportViewer control in aspx page which shows up the report perfectly fine in an iframe on my local machine. However, when the solution is deployed to Azure cloud service, the iframe shows up empty. No errors shown. I've also added below code in my web.config still no luck.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
```

Can anyone help on this? 
Thanks!

Comment: You might have to set special permissions on that IFRAME to allow js code to run, especially if it is loading content from a different domain.

Comment: Iframe and permissions doesn't seem to be the issue. I have other iframes in my application which are working fine. I even tried the url on a separate browser tab, which, again, works on local but not on the deployed version.
Moerever, I tried from the Azure instance itself, still same issue. No errors shown.